# mariadb server wont start, modular dependency problems?

Tags: rhel, services, mariadb, systemctl

I'm trying to create a maridb table on a rhel instance in my ec2 container, but everytime I try to start mariadb I get this:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mariadb-server.service Failed to start mariadb-server.service: Unit mariadb-server.service not found.
```

I've been searching for the answer to this for a day or two but no luck. I also ended coming across these modular dependency problems, but I honestly have no idea what any of this means. I'm still fairly new to learning Linux.

```
[root@ip-172-31-40-7 html]# yum list installed | grep mariadb Modular dependency problems:

Problem 1: conflicting requests - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBD-MySQL:4.046:8010020190322121447:073fa5fe-0.x86_64 Problem 2: conflicting requests - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8010020190322130042:16b3ab4d-0.x86_64 mariadb.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-backup.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-common.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-connector-c.x86_64 3.0.7-1.el8 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-connector-c-config.noarch 3.0.7-1.el8 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-errmsg.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-gssapi-server.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-server.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
mariadb-server-utils.x86_64 3:10.3.17-1.module+el8.1.0+3974+90eded84 @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
```

I also tried to remove packages, clean and reinstall but didn't work.

I'm still actively trying to find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL, I am thinking that `perl-DBD-MySQL` could be tied to an installation of MySQL on your server. If you don't need it maybe you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed mysql packages and ran the following : it instantly started!

```
[root@myhost]# systemctl start mariadb.service
[root@myhost]# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-02-28 20:35:07 UTC; 19s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 8981 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8911 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8887 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8949 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
    Tasks: 30 (limit: 4998)
   Memory: 76.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─8949 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
```